# I am trying to insert google maps in my project but getting an error

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, sorry if this sounds off

this is the error showen in console when compiling :

### Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

this is the piece of code to insert the componet in App.js :

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SimpleMap from './SimpleMap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SimpleMap />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SimpleMap code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
 
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;
 
class SimpleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "AIzaSyAEKXIE54WnL96aA4qln5bEzU3uOGKqhyo"}}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text="My Marker"
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default SimpleMap;
```

Comment: add SimpleMap component along with explanation of what you are trying to achieve in detail

Answer (score 0):

It is because your SimpleMap component might be empty, Just paste this code in your component(SimpleMap)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';
class Map extends Component {
   render() {
   const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 } }
        defaultZoom = { 13 }
      >
      </GoogleMap>
   ));
   return(
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} /> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
        />
      </div>
   );
   }
};
export default Map;
```

and add this google map script (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE) in your index.html

Lastly just install react-google-maps package using yarn or npm

```
yarn add react-google-maps
npm install react-google-maps
```

Comment: when I try to install google-map-react I get this error                                                        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from google-map-react@2.1.9
npm ERR! node_modules/google-map-react
npm ERR!   google-map-react@"*" from the root project

Comment: Try using yarn `yarn add react-google-maps`

Comment: I forsed the installation of the module with npm i --forse but the same error

Comment: I am trying to install google-map-react package with yarn because the package is not supported with my react-version @17.0.2.